# Setting globally defined defaults for certain table options

Tags: tabulator

I am curious to know if you could set a default global option for all tabulator tables. I want these options set on all tabulator tables throughout the application

```
ajaxLoaderLoading: "<div class='spinner'><div class='loading_circle'></div></div>",
placeHolder: "No Data Available",
```

My first thought was to use module extension but I don't believe that is a solution I am looking for. Ultimately I just want to avoid declaring the same default options for all tables. Any ideas or insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If this solution worked please accept the answer or else if you still have issue let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that would be to edit in Tabulator.js Library and hard code it, I wouldn't suggest doing that if other developer updates it your code will break.

You can set a global string for

```
"<div class='spinner'><div> class='loading_circle'></div></div>"
```

and "No Data Available" use it everywhere you initialize Tabulator

Comment: Yeah that's about the conclusion I had come to. It would be nice to specify certain options as defaults/standard, but explicitly declaring on each table isn't too much of a problem. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

wrap your call to Tabulator in a function or a custom class and just instantiate your custom code with a config object that can extend/override your default settings object.

Comment: Can you show the example?